# best practice in numerically computing the velocity from set of position data

Tags: numerical-methods, mathematical-modeling

I have extracted a data consisting of $x$ and $y$ positions of a thing I am tracking using a certain software. The thing is, 1 second video worth translates to 60 frames during analysis.

This means that I am getting 60 data points for every second of video. Now I am torn about how to compute the velocity of this object.

(a) Average velocity. It is possible that frame 1 and frame 60 will have exactly the same position, but the object may have moved in between. This means the average velocity is zero. But it doesn't reflect the story.

(b) Instantaneous velocity. So I can compute the velocity at each point and will have loads of data.

I was wondering what the best practice for this is, especially in mathematical modelling?

Comment: Well you can only calculate the average velocity for each interval of 1/60th of a second, it's never possible to calculate instantaneous velocity, so it seems like you are presenting yourself with a false dilemma here. In any case, if the data is accurate, then I don't see the problem with using the smaller time interval. This seems ultimately more like a statistical question though, i.e. you might want to use longer time intervals to have a lower expected error, but if you don't have a method to calculate your expected error then all of those considerations seem like they should be moot.